# Alternatives to Select & Paste in Excel Interop?

Tags: excel, vb.net, select, interop, paste

I'm writing a snippet of code that is supposed to find the last used rows and copy and paste the last two of them in order to add a "new row" without removing the border. Here is the (working) code I wrote for it

```vb
    Dim ExcelApp As New Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim c = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\some_files.xlsm")
    Dim f = c.Sheets("SomeSheet")
    Dim lRow As Integer = f.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    f.Range("A" & lRow - 1 & ":BG" & lRow).Copy
    f.Range("A" & lRow & ":BG" & lRow + 1).Select
    f.Paste
```

Now you can see I used the Range.Select method and then .Paste.
The thing is, I know it's a bad move but I couldn't seems to find a way to paste into specific cells without selecting them first.

Comment: [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to copy and past them? That is not a standard procedure to actually "copy" the data programatically. You'd use `.Copy` if you needed to place the content into the Clipboard (for a user to re-use it). But perhaps you wanted to avoid loops and such.

If you need to copy the data and/or format, you'd typically use code like this:

```
ColIndex = 4
ColCount = 5    ' number of columns to copy
For ic = ColIndex To ColIndex + ColCount
    ' Copy values
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(8, ic).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(4, ic).Value
    ' Copy particular properties
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(13, ic).NumberFormat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(4, ic).NumberFormat
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(14, ic).Font.Bold = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(4, ic).Font.Bold
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(14, ic).Interior.Color = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(4, ic).Interior.Color
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(14, ic).Borders.Color = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(4, ic).Borders.Color
    ' Copy all formatting at once (like with Format Painter)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(16, ic).Style = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(4, ic).Style
Next
```

In this example, it will copy values from `D4:I4` to `D8:I8`.

Unfotunately, you CAN'T use following code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("D8:I8") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("D4:I4")   ' WRONG!!
```

Just out of my cusiosity and self-education, I played with another way to copy format and it works too:

```
Dim CopyRng As Range, PasteRng As Range
Set CopyRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("D4:I4")
Set PasteRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("D28:I28")
CopyRng.Copy
PasteRng.Parent.Activate
PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

It does activates not require selection of the cells too.

Comment: I actually don't need the data but the format of the cells (Border, blue and white strips, etc, etc ...). Does `.Value` works with that too ?

Comment: No, `.Value` contains only value of the cell(s). I've modified my answer to include format copying.

Comment: It's pretty much what I wanted ! I just need to find how to copy borders style and it'll be fine. Thanks :)

Comment: Not at all. I've just added another way, very similar to your initial code. One just have to remember, that the copied format will stay in clipboard until erased either programatically or by user.